# Passing Params in The Same Screen. React Native

Tags: react-native

I know how to pass parameters to other screen. For example:

```
    <Flatlist 
    data={SOMEDATA}
    renderItem={(itemData) => (
              <Button
                onPress={() => {
                  props.navigation.navigate("myScreen", {
                    myId: itemData.item.id,
                  })
                }}
              >
             </Button>
    />
```

Then I can access `myId` on the `myScreen` screen by `props.route.params.myId`, But I don't know how to access it in the same screen I am using (same js file). if I write `props.route.params.myId`, I will get this error :

> undifined is not an object (evaluating 'props.route.params.myId'

any help please?

Comment: On the same screen, you have two options. the best is to use a state variable. the second option is to set the params of navigation in the screen by navigation.setParams. follow this link for more information: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#updating-params

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to set a property in the state of your current screen?

if so, what you need is a state

assuming you are using a functional react component and not a class based component, what you need to do is to introduce a state to your component

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
```

when ever you want to change your state, you just need to call the `setState(myNewObj)` function,
whenever you want to access your state
you can just call for `state`

the `initiateState` can be anything

in your case something like

```
const [myId, setMyId] = useState(-1);
```

I suggest you take alook at the official React Documentation

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#basic-hooks